# Error when I run php artisan migrate command

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.3, database-migration

I am trying to add a commenting system on my blog application however I get this error when trying to run comment migration which seems to have nothing to do with my current `comments` migration file, but a previous `post_tag` migration file

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'post_tag' already exists (SQL:
    create table `post_tag` (
      `id` int unsigned not null  auto_increment primary key,
      `post_id` int unsigned not null, 
      `tag_id` int unsigned not null
    ) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
```

This is my `comments` migration file

```
<?php

//2017_01_16_101128_create_comments_table.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->text('comment');
        $table->boolean('approved');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

    });

    Schema::table('comments', function($table){
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->
                     onDelete('cascade');
        });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropForeign(['post_id']);
    Schema::drop('comments');
}
}
```

and this is my `post_tag` migration file

```
<?php

2016_12_18_230831_create_post_tag_table.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostTagTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->unsigned();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('post_tag');
}
}
```

How do I get rid of this error or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CreatePostTagTable` migration you may wont to change

```
$table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('tag_id')->unsigned();
```

to

```
$table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tag');
```

There was a duplication.

Then manually remove `post_tag` table. It could have be created once again. You may also want to check on your `migration` table in your database as there could be a record of. `post_tag` table. If so remove it. Then you could run migration safely.

Additionally since you are creating a `pivot table` you don't probably gonna need a `$table->increments('id');`. It could be depend on your situation. In most cases you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to manually drop the table in mysql:

```
mysql> drop table post_tag;
```

Then run the migration again

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I tried doing as you suggested now I get the error  `  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `post_
  tag` add constraint `post_tag_tag_id_foreign` foreign key (`tag_id`) references `` ())`

Comment: if the database does not have production data and the project is under development, you're better off dropping the entire database, creating it, making the change that Gayan suggested below and then running php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
Drop table post_tag;
```

**AND**

*Delete post_tag* migration from *migrations table*

After run the migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

Hope this work for you!